# html agility pack: how to extract raw text

Tags: html-agility-pack

Quick question, how do I get all raw text (i.e., removing all html tags) using html agility pack?

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(html);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download source code from [Html Agility Pack page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/44954) (look for "*Html Agility Pack 1.4.0 Source*" file) there is folder Html2Txt that contains the code you need (look for the HtmlToText class in **HtmlConvert.cs** file).

Comment: Thanks Rafal. I was using an older version which does not have such function.